# How should my C# application securely connect to my AWS EC2 database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, apache, amazon-ec2

As I see it, I have two options: access my database with a ReSTful (http) webservice connection, or directly connecting to MySQL. I've found that it isn't that easy to directly access MySQL (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) and that the remote connection is IP-specific (my app would run in many places and the IPs won't be static).

How should applications connect to databases? Directly or through the httpd server?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow a MySQL user account to connect from any host (IP addresses).

for example, 
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

Comment: Ty for the response.

I was able connect directly to my database with it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how secure you need it to be.  We configure an OpenVPN server on the same VPC as the MySQL server and use that to control access to our systems. There is no direct connect to MySQL.